# How to access a Django many-to-many model, from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, django

Given a Django template variable with a many-to-many model, is it possible to pass that to a Javascript function, and access it?

(What I'm trying to get, is a list of the groups, including pk, that the current user belongs to).

For example, if I have a user *jsmith* that belongs to two groups, *alpha* and *beta*:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    mangle_data("{{ user.name }}", "{{ user.groups }}", "{{ user.groups.all }"");
</script>
</html>

function mangle_data(username, groups, all) {
    alert("username = " + username); // works. output = "jsmith"
    alert("user.groups = " + groups); // output = "django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object"
    alert("all = " + all); // output = "[Group alpha; Group beta;]"
}
```

In all cases, the parameter passed to Javascript, is a single flattened string. Ideally, I'd get an object, or even a list that contained both group names, and group pk.

Granted, I could *find* the pk of a group, given its name - but that's a lot more steps. If I can get the data from the Django template directly into Javascript, it would be much cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I wound up solving this, was to use a Context Processor to format the data, and pass it to a template variable:

```
context_processors.py

def site_settings(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user_groups = "+".join(['{"id":%s, "name":"%s"}' % 
            (grp['id'], grp['name']) for grp in rquest.user.groups.values()])
    else:
        user_groups = ''
    return {'USER_GROUPS': user_groups, }

template.html

<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    mangle_data("{{ USER_GROUPS|safe }"");
</script>
</html>

handle_data.js

function mangle_data(groups) {
    var groups_json = '[' + groups.split('+').join(',') + ']';
    var groups_OBJ = JSON.parse(groups_json); // this is now a Javascript object.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about [serializing `user.groups`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#serializing-django-objects) in a context variable?

If you serialize these to JSON, you can easily retrieve parse it from your page's JS.

Comment: Is there some way of doing that directly inside a Django template?

Comment: @JohnC You could always write a template tag / filter that does it.